# Иногда не сразу работает кнопка на jquery

Tags: jquery, button, корзина

Есть обычная кнопка которая чистит корзину,

```
$("#clear").click(function(){ //очистка
newprice = 0;
newcount = 0;
id = 0;
window.localStorage[keyprice] = newprice;
window.localStorage[keyid] = id;
window.localStorage[keycount] = newcount;
$('#cart span#price').html(newprice+' руб. ').attr("price",newprice);
$('#cart span.count').html(newcount);
})
```

Но иногда, а именно когда переходишь из магазина на главную и обратно, она перестает работать. Можно кликнуть на кнопку "добавить в корзину" и все снова заработает и она будет чистить как и должна. Почему может быть такой глюк? Или если есть мысли куда думать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: а где этот код расположен? можете показать что с верху и с низу, или точнее, во что она обернута

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){...} Обернуто вот в это, может в этом проблема ? Еще эта функция была внутри другой функции (добавления товара)... И видимо в этом было проблема, так как я ее вытащил за пределы и все, теперь работает исправно =)
Спасибо большое за наводящий вопросы!